# Flutter Continues Speech to text Recognition

Tags: flutter, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, flutter-dependencies, google-cloud-speech

When app Opened by user then start **Speech listening and when user in background or exit to the app then stop listening.**

Is that possible with Flutter ????

I was already tried **speech_recognition** plugin but that was not able to Recognise speech continuously when app is opened.
Please help me how can i make it possible?

Comment: Please tell  us what you really want to do here. Your explaination is not clear